# Hosting SeviceStack on Mono without a webserver

Tags: mono, servicestack

As I was reading about how to run [ServiceStack as a daemon on Linux](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux) I was wondering if a webserver such as apache or nginx is needed at all now that servicestack has razor and markdown view egines.

If I need more than one website, then I would still use nginx as a reverse proxy, but given that I only need a single website on a linux box would there be any problems in simply deploying Servicestack as a deamon that listens on port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successful done this. I have done that to run on heroku. If you are interested project is hosted over [github](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackHeroku). Code currently in F# but you can easily convert that to C#. And it is port of Razor project you find out at servicestack [github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.SelfHost) . It work with mono. If you want any specific details please let me know.